# iPhone - listing files in remote directory (before downloading)

Tags: iphone, directory-listing

I am wondering if it is possible to list files in a remote (public) directory 
such as http://www.mysite.com/mydirectory/  in objective C with the iPhone SDK.

If anyone could point me in the right direction regarding this it would be great.

Thanks.